# How is N defined?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I understand that $\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Q}$ are defined as ...
$$\mathbb{Z} = \mathbb{N} \cup \{ -n \mid n \in \mathbb{N} \}$$
$$\mathbb{Q} = \left\{ \frac{a}{b} \mid a,b \in \mathbb{Z} \right\}$$
... but how is $\mathbb{N}$ defined?
(and how is the order on these sets defined?)

Comment: You can make a construction of natural numbers based on set theory by defining $0 := \{ \}$ and the successor of $n$ (denoted by $S(n)$) as $ S(n) = n \cup \{n\}$.

Comment: Side note: I once read somewhere (I think the book was called "The Music of Primes") that everything in math was invented/developed by humans, except for the natural numbers which where defined by god.

Comment: I don't usually go into these philosophical discussions, but there's no need for humans to invent maths for it to be true.

Comment: @SydKerckhove: I can't recall the exact terminology used, I figured that "invented" wasn't exactly appropriate so I slashed it with "developed".

Comment: $\mathbb{N}$ is not a ring.

Comment: @IsaacZebulunBurke Oh right, my bad!

Comment: @barak: http://www.brainyquote.com/quotes/authors/l/leopold_kronecker.html

Comment: @GEdgar: Nice! All in all, I'd say my memory served me pretty well on this one... But thinking about it, he (or she) only had to make the integer $1$, along with the plus, the minus and the infinite-repetition operations.

Comment: @Workaholic You should make your comment an answer, maybe with a word on how the ordering is defined.

Comment: @SpamIAm $ $ Done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a construction of natural numbers based on set theory by defining $0:=\{\,\}=\varnothing$ and the successor of $n$ $($denoted by $S(n))$ as $S(n)=n\cup\{n\}$. And so for instance :

- $1:=S(0)=\varnothing\cup\{\varnothing\}=\{\varnothing\}$.
- $2:=S(1)=\{\varnothing\}\cup\{\{\varnothing\}\}=\{\{\varnothing\},\{\{\varnothing\}\}\}$.

Now, for what concerns the ordering: Let $a,b\in\mathbf{N}$, then $a\gt b$ if and only if $b\in a$.

Comment: You haven't defined addition, so your definition of order is incomplete

Comment: The definition of order can be done simpler: $a < b \iff a \in b$. This works because $S(n) = \{0,\dotsc,n\}$.

Comment: @SydKerckhove I was just describing how ordering was defined after having properly defined the operation of addition.

Comment: @kahen Thanks, added.